# Render another controllers view as partial (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry, only have been using rails for 10 day and I'm completely lost. Have a post model/controller and comment model/controller.

In post/show, I want to click an ajax button and replace a div (#addcomment) with the partial generated from comment/new (The new action takes two params and builds a comment for an ajax form partial). The comment/new partial is an add comment form with remote => true.

Anyone willing to point me in the right direction?

Tried using an ajax button in the view, that calls an action that replaces the div with the comment/new but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't remove your question. Write the answer, so it may help others.

Comment: Can you post your code? Consider using pastebin or gist it.  I take it you have modelled (their relationships, between) posts and comments via AR?